# How to return array of char in recursive function in c

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I have a program like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * rekursif(int m, int n, char angka[100], int j){
    int i;
    char array[100][100];
    for(i=m; i<=n; i++){
        char angka2[100];
        strcpy(angka2,angka);
        sprintf(array[j], "%s %d", angka, i);
        sprintf(angka, "%s %d", angka, i);
        rekursif(i+1,n,angka2,j+1);
    }
    if(i>n){
        return (char *)array;
    }
}

int main(){
    char *p;
    int i;
    char str[100];
    p = rekursif(1,3,str,0);
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(p);i++){
        printf("%s",p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output program that I expect : 
1
2
3
23
12
123

the question are : 
1. how to return array of char in recursive function?
2. how to initialize dynamic size array (p) in main program as big as size of array in recursive function?

thank you :)

Comment: do you know how many items are going to be in that array BEFORE you start recursing? If you don't, then you'd have to allocate at least as much space as you THINK you might need (and then some), or don't use a fixed-size array. e.g. a linked list instead.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers and use a real data structure as Marc is suggesting. You could use `std::string` and just concatenate strings. Or build a structure for the job in pure C if needed.

Comment: Can you please properly document your code so that the one who examines can easily understand what you're doing in the code

Comment: MarcB , Loic : I will try to use array first, thanks anyway for the comment :)

@hariprasad : I have edited my question and explain what the output that I expect. Thanks :)